# Send custom commands with zigbee2mqtt

Tags: mqtt, home-assistant

Is it possible to send custom commands with zigbee2mqtt? I have found that I can send commands with Mosquitto, but they don't seem to be transferred directly. I am trying to send the commands to a Nordtronic dimmer.

If I send `{"brightness":100}` from Mosquitto, zigbee2mqtt sends
`{"brightness":100,"linkquality":191,"state":"ON"}` to the device. I would like to know if the device can accept `{"brightness":100,"linkquality":191,"state":"OFF"}`, so I can change the set brightness without turning the light on.

A question that is somewhat related:
[How to automatically dim the bathroom light at night with Home Assistant](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/6117/how-to-automatically-dim-the-bathroom-light-at-night-with-home-assistant)

Comment: What happens if you send {"brightness":100, "state":"OFF"} ?  Or perhaps if you send two separate commands one after the other, to set brightness to 20 and then state to off ?

Comment: Oh. I noticed that you were able to achieve what you wanted via another method. Perhaps you can add what you learnt here as comments or just close this question if the other one serves the purpose.

Comment: if I send send {"brightness":100, "state":"OFF"}, zigbee2mqtt won't accept it and throws in error instead of forwarding the message. Maybe devices can easily get damaged if they receive strange requests, that could be a reason why it is not possible.

Comment: I have added a link to the other question, it is quite different, but maybe someone will find it useful. I am considering deleting this question because it does not seem that useful.